How was this character killed in Deadpool and Wolverine?
In Deadpool and Wolverine (2024) there's a scene where X-23 faces off against Juggernaut and easily slices off his feet and then his head. How was she able to do this? Isn't Juggernaut supposed to be practically invulnerable to all physical attacks? Everything I've found by searching has suggested that Wolverine's claws wouldn't be able to do much damage to him, so I wouldn't expect X-23 to come close to enough power either.

"practically invulnerable". Answered your own question there.

@Valorum I mean yes, but everything I've found by searching has suggested that Wolverine's claws wouldn't be able to do much damage, so I wouldn't expect X-23 to come close to enough power either.

What exactly have you found that contradicts that showing?

Since he is from one of any number of different universes/timelines one possibility is that he is more vulnerable than the one in our/current universe.

@LogicDictates Admittedly a lot of the sources are theoretical comparisons between the two. The one canon reference is from X-men #102 where his claws didn't do much of anything (ref), but that's a very early comic.

@David K - It's also a different version of the character from a different universe and medium. Comicbook Juggernaut is powered by magic and has much more impressive feats than the movie version, who is a non-magical mutant. So movie Juggernaut should be measured by his own showings, not those of the comicbook version.

The Juggernaut that appears in Deadpool and Wolverine is implicitly the same one from X-Men: The Last Stand, as he wears the same costume. (Vinnie Jones was approached to reprise the role but turned it down.) That version of Juggernaut differs from the comic book version in that he is a mutant whose only power is being almost impossible to stop once he starts running. He is therefore just as vulnerable to X-23's claws as any of Cassandra Nova's other henchmen.
The Juggernaut is not the only Variant in Deadpool & Wolverine that's more vulnerable than their comic book counterpart. Sabertooth (who also canonically has regenerative abilities) is beheaded by Wolverine with ease, while

 the Deadpool Variant "Nicepool" lacks Deadpool's healing factor and is quite brutally shot dead as a result.


Thats what I remember from the comics, that once he starts running he cant be stopped, when he was attached in Deadpool and Wolverine he was just standing there.  So if you combine the 2 kind of he may be almost invulnerable if he is running (unstoppable) but if standing still he is completely vulnerable.
